# pandas gather first not null values from different columns on the same index

Tags: python, pandas

I have queried a huge table where majority of the rows in each columns are null (`None`) for each single `id` (there are multiple rows for each `id`). I want to squash these so I'll have one row per `id`

I'll provide a mock example of the input:

```
    id  var1  var2
0   1  None  None
1   1  None     x
2   2  None     k
3   3  None  None
4   1  None  None
5   1     y   NOT
6   3     p  None
7   2    ss  None
8   2  None  None
```

And here would be the mock example of the output:

```
    id var1  var2
0   1    y     x
1   2   ss     k
2   3    p  None
```

Note how `"NOT"` from `var2` column did not make it, because it's the second non-null value for `id==1`.

The following snippet works if there are only one value for each id:

```
df = df.set_index('id')
cs = [df[col].dropna() for col in df]
pd.concat(cs, axis=1)
```

But if there are multiple values (such as `NOT` in the example), this throw an error.

Is there an easy way to aggregate the first not null value for each column for each `id`? Thanks.

Here's the mock example pandas dataframe, I'll have a lot more columns and rows for the real dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, None, None],[1, None, "x"],[2, None, "k"],[3,None, None], [1, None, None], [1, "y", "NOT"], [3, "p", None], [2, "ss", None], [2, None, None]])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
idColumnName = 'id' # Define id column name
def funcGroup(x): # Define grouping function
    columns = [x for x in x.columns if x!=idColumnName] # Get columns that are not id column
    dictValues = {} # Init a dictionary
    for col_ in columns: # For each column ...
        nonNullValues = x.loc[~x[col_].isnull(), col_] # Get non null values
        firstNonNullValue = np.nan # Init result value as null
        if nonNullValues.shape[0]>0: firstNonNullValue = nonNullValues.iloc[0] # If there are not null values return first
        dictValues[col_] = firstNonNullValue # Fill the dictionary
    return pd.Series(dictValues, columns) # Return a pandas Serie

df.groupby([idColumnName]).apply(funcGroup).reset_index() # Group by your id column and apply defined function
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check with `first` `: first not null value will be returned`

```
df.groupby(0).first().reset_index()
Out[582]: 
   0     1     2
0  1  None  None
1  2  None     k
2  3  None  None
```

Comment: `df.groupby('id', as_index=False).first(skipna=True)` looks like you forgot the `skipna` kwargs

Comment: `first` doesn't seem to skip null, `skipna` is not a param of the `first` function apparently.